# UITableViewCell reuse over View Controller instances

Tags: ios, uitableview

Every time VC is showed - `UITableView` loads cells from storyboard. And then successfully reuse them while scrolling. But every time showing controller - performes loading from storyboard. I would like to avoid this behavior.

Is there any way to reuse cells between `UITableView` instances this way?

Comment: Sorry, What do you mean *produce loading*?

Comment: @WorldOfWarcraft I mean "perform" :)

Comment: I am not clear about what your question is. Why do you want avoid loading?

Comment: @WorldOfWarcraft I would like cells to be reused when I pop and push view controller.

Comment: I think which is quite un necessary. Why you are more concerned about this? Let them create it again when VC is re created. What is the benefit of the way you suggested?

Comment: @AnilVarghese this takes some time before my view controller can be presented. I would like to speedup pushing view controller.

Comment: Did you use Time Profiler tool from Xcode instruments, to detect problem place in your view controller loading? I'm pretty sure, that it isn't cell loading, because in this case you will get problems with scroll at the beginning of table scrolling...

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko yep, it is `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. And I have some lags while scrolling when some cells types appears first time.

Comment: You want to make global reuse, but this isn't good idea - fast moving cells between superview tables can cause different strange issues.

Comment: I suggest 2 ways: 1)improve your code; 2)use async cell loading (but in this case you need to check is cell initialised before you configure it)

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that using storyboards. You will have to create a XIB file with a custom UITableViewCell. You can then reuse it:

```
UITableViewCell* customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId"];
if(!customCell)
{
    customCell = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"UITableViewCellXibName" owner:nil options:nil][0];
}
```